# Converting csv data into transactions for arules and market basket analysis

Tags: r, transactions, arules

I am a beginner to R and I would really appreciate all help. I have some data, which I cleaned, removed duplicates,etc. Now, I have this data in a csv file, my main issue is that I am not able to convert it into transactions. I am only able to convert them into lists, but not as transactions.

[Please let me know how I can change this data to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQy7v.png)

[This data (like as transactions)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFCeu.png)

Please help, TIA!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Look at the manual page of read.transactions using `? read.transactions`. There is an example that does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

To convert csv file into transaction file use this code.
suppose tfile is the name of csv file

```
colnames = names(tfile)

bas_str = ""

for(row in 1:nrow(x)){ 


    if(row !=1){                          
            bas_str = paste0( bas_str, "\n")}
    bas_str = paste0(bas_str,row,",")     
    for(col in 2:length(colnames)){      
           if(col != 2){                       
                  bas_str = paste0(bas_str,",")}
    bas_str = paste0(bas_str,colnames[col],"=",tfile[row,col])}}
```